# If I use jQuery Mobile do I need to implement a scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, scrollbar, tinyscrollbar

If I construct a long list in jQuery Mobile and than turn it into an App with PhoneGap does the scroll bar automatically surface like in a browser window, or do I have to include one like this http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get default scroll if you create app using Phonegap. You need to use some third party libraries like [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Learn more here : http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/07/19/jquery-mobile-scrolling/